# My App is not showing in Samsung Galaxy Note 3

Tags: android, publish, android-screen-support

Hi all i need a help on this problem ,i have an application published on google play ,the app works fine for all mobile devices and Tab 7 and Tab 10 ,but it can't be visible for Samsung Not 3.and i found it in supported devices list but it was disabled and i couldn't make it enabled at all ..
here is the manifest file

```
       <compatible-screens>

        <!-- no small size screens -->


        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />

        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />

        <screen android:screenSize="large" 
            android:screenDensity="480" />

        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />

        <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="213"
            android:screenSize="large" />
    </compatible-screens>
    <!--
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />



    -->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        />
     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"  />



       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.input_methods"
        android:required="false" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.tawasol.think.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.tawasol.think.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- Notify Me permissions -->
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <!--   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> -->
```

any help please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Completely delete the `<compatible-screens>` element.

Step #2: Decide whether or not you want to support small screens or not. Your now-deleted `<compatible-screens>` said "no, do not support small screens". Your `<supports-screens>` element says "yes, support small screens". You cannot do both.

Step #3: If the answer to Step #2 was "no, do not support small screens", then change `android:smallScreens` to `false`.

Step #4: Add `android:xlargeScreens="true"`, since your now-deleted `<compatible-screens>` element claimed that you wanted to support `xlarge` screens.